# Finding the derivative of $f(x)=\int_0^{x^2} \frac{e^{t^2}+1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I wanted to know if my approach at finding the derivative of

$$f(x)=\int_0^{x^2} \frac{e^{t^2}+1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt = \int_0^{x^2}g(t) dt$$

is correct. I am mainly concerned with my use of substitutions; I don't know if my substitutions are entirely correct nor whether they were necessary (perhaps a more direct approach than substitution existed). Thanks in advance!

*My solution*

Let $u=x^2, v=t^2$. Then

$$f(x)=\int_0^{x^2} \frac{e^{t^2}+1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt = \int_0^u\frac{e^v+1}{\sqrt{1-v}}dv= \int_0^ug(v) dv$$

We know $g(v)=\frac{e^v+1}{\sqrt{1-v}}$ is continuous for all $v$ satisfying $\sqrt{1-v}\neq 0$; i.e., $v \neq 1$. Therefore, due to the FTC,

$$\int_0^ug(v)dv$$

is continuos at any closed interval not containing 1, and differentiable at any open interval not containing 1, and its derivative is

$$\frac{d}{du}\int_0^ug(v) dv=g(u)=\frac{e^u+1}{\sqrt{1-u}}=\frac{e^{x^2}+1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} $$

EDIT:

Now, by application of the chain rule,

$$\frac{d}{dx}f = \frac{d}{du}f \frac{d}{dx}u = \frac{e^{x^2}+1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} 2x$$

Comment: You found $df/du$, but the question asked for $df/dx$.

Comment: I thought substituting back from $u$ to $x^2$ at the final step accomplished that. Is that not so? Thanks.

Comment: More precisely, letting $f(x)=h(x^2)$, you found $h'$. Now use the chain rule to compute $f'.$

Comment: Oh! I see. What a miss on my part. I've edited the question to add your correction. Did I understand your point correctly? If so, please post your comment as an answer so I can mark it.

Comment: When in doubt try something simpler, e.g. $\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{x^2}t^{n-1}dt$ for $n\ne0$.

Comment: lafinur, your own final edit is, in my opinion, a more appropriate solution to your initial question than the answer you accepted, because it is conceptually simpler. But your notation "$\frac{d}{dx}f = \frac{d}{du}f \frac{d}{dx}u$" is not quite correct, you should give another name that $f$ to the function of $u$ you defined and differentiated previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You calculation is not quite correct, as your final result lacks plugging in the $x^2$ bound into the function.

If I’m not mistaken, usually the computation goes as follows.
The FTC I states that $$\frac d {dx}\,\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(t)\,dt=f(b(x))\, b'(x)-f(a(x))\, a'(x)$$
In your case $$f(t)= \frac{e^{t^2}+1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} ,\quad a(x)=0 ,\quad b(x)=x^2$$
So the derivative is simply $$\frac{e^{x^4}+1}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}\cdot 2x -\frac{e^{0^2}+1}{\sqrt{1-0^2}}\cdot 0$$
Which reduces to just the first term.

Comment: That theorem does not appear in the book I'm using, had no idea it existed. Could you refer me to a demonstration of it? And thanks for sharing it.

Comment: I see you say it is the FTC, but the TFC does not appear formulated for bounds of the form $a(x), b(x)$ in the FTC chapter of my book nor in the FTC Wikipedia link, nor any other source I can check.

Comment: Forget my comments, I just demonstrated it myself. It makes complete sense. I appreciate your answer very much, thank you!

Comment: @lafinur sorry i just saw your comments right now. I call it FTC I since it basically is exactly that but it is more formally known as the leibniz rule, or feynman's method if youre applying it to integrate something. Wiki gives the multivariable version but you can easily infer the single variable one. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule