# Derivative of integral where both bounds are functions of $x$: $f(x)=\int_{\sqrt{x}}^{x^3}\frac{t+1}{\sqrt{1+2^t}} dt$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives

I was requested to find the derivative of the following function

$$f(x)=\int_{\sqrt{x}}^{x^3}\frac{t+1}{\sqrt{1+2^t}} dt$$

The fact that both the upper and lower bounds of the integral are functions of $x$ caught me by surprise. However, I made my best attempt at applying the fundamental theorem of calculus, and was wondering if my solution is correct (since online calculators, like WolframAlpha, fail at calculating this derivative).

*My solution*

$i.$ Firstly, notice that $g(t)=\frac{t+1}{\sqrt{1+2^t}}$ is continuous for all $t$, since $\sqrt{1+2^t}>0$ for all $t$.

$ii.$ The fundamental theorem of calculus states that $f$ will be continuous at any closed interval $[\sqrt{x}, x^3]$, and differentiable at any open interval $(\sqrt{x}, x^3)$.

$iii.$ However, the intervals stated in $ii$ are defined in $\mathbb{R}$ only for $x\geq0$. Therefore, $f$ will be continuous for any closed interval belonging to $[0, \infty)$ and any open interval belonging to $[0, \infty)$, and its derivative will be

$$f'(x)= \frac{x+1}{\sqrt{1+2^x}}$$

Is this solution correct? I'm suspicious of whether the restriction imposed in step $iii$ is actually the way to properly deal with the fact that both bounds are functions of $x$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is incorrect, refer to the formula I gave in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4530894/595084

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that

$$f'(x)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_{\sqrt{x}}^{x^3}\frac{t+1}{\sqrt{1+2^t}}~\mathrm{d}t=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_{0}^{x^3}\frac{t+1}{\sqrt{1+2^t}}~\mathrm{d}t-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_0^{\sqrt{x}}\frac{t+1}{\sqrt{1+2^t}}~\mathrm{d}t=\frac{3x^2(x^3+1)}{\sqrt{1+2^{x^3}}}-\frac{\sqrt{x}+1}{2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1+2^{\sqrt{x}}}}$$

using just the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus along with the chain rule, which you can simplify further if you want to.

Comment: It appears we have effectively the same solution.  I'll delete mine.

Comment: Excellently explained. Thank you so much!